# JS/TS: Getting access to a value wrapped in a promise?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an Object where the key is a stringified object and the value is a Promise that eventually resolves to a font object.
I use `Promise.all` to wait for them all to resolve.

After this, I log the object in console and it looks like:

```
{
  '{"family":"Roboto","style":"Regular","postscriptName":"Roboto-Light"}': Promise {
    {
      family: 'Roboto',
      style: 'Regular',
      postscriptName: 'Roboto-Light'
    }
  },
  '{"family":"Roboto","style":"Regular","postscriptName":"Roboto-Medium"}': Promise {
    {
      family: 'Roboto',
      style: 'Bold',
      postscriptName: 'Roboto-Bold'
    }
  }
}
```

I want to enumerate through the object to ensure each postscript name in they key matches the one in the value:

```
let allPostscriptNamesMatch = true;

for (const font in myObj) {
   const parsedFont = JSON.parse(font);
   if (parsedFont.postscriptName !==) myObj[font].postscriptName) {
      allPostscriptNamesMatch = false;
   } 
}
```

my problem is: `myObj[font].postscriptName` is empty because it's wrapped in a Promise.  How can I get access to that?

Comment: *I use Promise.all to wait for them all to resolve.* Where are you doing this? Can you show where the object is being generated?

Comment: Thats an asyncronous call, you should capture it  with then() callback fn

Comment: There are better approaches if you show how you're constructing the object shown in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use `.then`:

```js
myObj[font].postscriptName.then(name => {
    if (parsedFont.postscriptName != name) {
        allPostscriptNamesMatch = false;
    }
});
```

Comment: ah right.  Thank you.  I just adapted the same approach and used `await`.  Thank you!

Comment: I didn't use await in the answer since you never mention being in an async function, though that would work better.